# Twitter API - Load Hash Tag from certain users

Tags: twitter

For my project I wish to have a feed from the developers on the homepage of the site, to allow users to find out what is going on; whilst allowing the developers to quickly update the feed without having to use a certain user and allowing them to show what they have been doing.

This means that I want to find a specific hash tag for example `#dev` from a group of approximately 4 or 5 users.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be achieved? I have tried searching and not found anything.

I would like to get this data in JSON format preferably for formatting either via javascript or php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing about with the Twitter API I have found a way to do this.

Firstly you must know a little about the [search api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).

So in order to display a search from one user is fairly easy, you just use the following url:
`http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23hashtag+from:user1`
This will return all results from the `user1` containing `#hashtag` in their tweet (remembering that %23 is #).

So in order to return from more than one user you have to use the following url:
`http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23hashtag+from:user1+OR+from:user2`
Basically meaning that if you wish to add more users you include `+OR+` in your url.